# how to get top 10 requester from influxdb

Tags: influxdb

I am using influxdb version 1.7.9. 
I have below data in measurement name "tpam" and database name is "test". 
I have around 15000 rows with this data in measurement.
I am looking for query to get top 10 "Requester Name" and there count of requests in particular "Request Month" 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWGWM.png)

Comment: https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/functions/#top

Comment: Can you please help me with the query , i tried with these not working for me .